# usb external hard drive will not mount on boot

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, fstab

Server OS: Debian Stretch

fdisk -l http://paste.debian.net/932334

fstab http://paste.debian.net/932336

journalctl -xb paste.debian.net / 932337

zoneminder: wiki. zoneminder. com / Using_a_dediated_Hard_Drive

I have tried everything from specifying the UUID as seen in fstab to defining the hdd as /dev/sdb1 as seen in fdisk. No matter what I do the result is the same: see lines 877-900 (journalctl log). I need the drive to automount on boot so service zoneminder can utilize it.

Log:

```
-- The start-up result is done.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-803EA0A4\x2d2592\x2d4258\x2d9820\x2d242ECA6038AA.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-803EA0A4\x2d2592\x2d4258\x2d9820\x2d242ECA6038AA.device/start timed out.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-803EA0A4\x2d2592\x2d4258\x2d9820\x2d242ECA6038AA.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-803EA0A4\x2d2592\x2d4258\x2d9820\x2d242ECA6038AA.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd

-- 
-- Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-803EA0A4\x2d2592\x2d4258\x2d9820\x2d242ECA6038AA.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is timeout.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /media/external.
-- Subject: Unit media-external.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd

-- 
-- Unit media-external.mount has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
-- Subject: Unit local-fs.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd

-- 
-- Unit local-fs.target has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: media-external.mount: Job media-external.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-803EA0A4\x2d2592\x2d4258\x2d9820\x2d242ECA6038AA.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-803EA0A4\x2d2592\x2d4258\x2d9820\x2d242ECA6038AA.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
May 13 17:00:58 dvr systemd[1]: Started ifup for enp1s10.
-- Subject: Unit ifup@enp1s10.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

Comment: Oddly enough lines 595, 621 and 641 of journalctl output refer to /dev/sdb1 as being mounted. Can you post the output of 'lsblk -f' and also an output of a slightly complex command "udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb1)" (see https://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=343 for explanation). I suspect udev mounts your external disk somewhere (most likely under /run/media/root) before systemctl gets a chance to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the disk identifier (`Disk identifier: 803EA0A4-2592-4258-9820-242ECA6038AA` from the `fdisk -l` output) as the file system identifier (`UUID=` in fstab).  Those are not the same and not interchangeable.

You can find the file system identifier by doing `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep sdb1`.  Output will be something like:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 30 17:09 66629b27-c8cc-4919-b9e3-3aa494e4a7f0 -> ../../sdb1`

`66629b27-c8cc-4919-b9e3-3aa494e4a7f0` is the file system uuid and what you put after `UUID=` in `/etc/fstab`.